# php form issues

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I have a form with which I am trying to display a form with checkboxes, and then insert into a database whether or not those checkboxes are checked. Then, each time the page is called, check the value and append information to the html form to appropriate display the checkbox as checked or not.

I have modified the below code example to make it short, and I am aware that I am assigning the checked value to 'value', which won't do anything.

The approach of

```
<input type="checkbox" name="notice"  value="checked" checked/>
```

to display a checkbox as checked, while not valid html, works in every browser, and is based on the example [here](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms09.htm). I would prefer to stick with this approach.

Now, I don't see what is wrong with my code.

The first steps should be to retrieve the values from the database, of which onyl one row will be retrieved, as article_no is a primary key. If nothing is retrieved, then the variables are simply assigned "", which results in the checkbox being unchecked.

As the value is checked, if it is selected, this should be inserted into the database, and will show as checked upon next viewing of the page.

Now, as it is, this code compeltely fails. firebug does not show anything being sent or received in the console, no erros are recorded either with php or mysql, nothing appears in the database despite the fields and such being correct, no mysql errors are reported...

What is the problem?

```
The code:

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (isset($_GET["cmd"]))

  $cmd = $_GET["cmd"];

else
if (isset($_POST["cmd"]))

  $cmd = $_POST["cmd"];


  if (isset($_GET["pk"]))

  { $pk = $_GET["pk"];}
  if (isset($_POST["deleted"]))
  { $deleted = $_POST["deleted"];}
  if (isset($_POST["notice"]))
  { $notice = $_POST["notice"];}

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass", "db");

if (!$con) {

   echo "Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n". mysqli_connect_error();

   exit;

}
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$getformdata = $con->query("select * from TEST where ARTICLE_NO = '$pk'");

$checkDeleted = "";
$checkNotice = "";


  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getformdata))

  {

    $checkDeleted = $row['deleted'];

    $checkNotice = $row['notice'];

   } 
if($cmd=="submitinfo"){
$statusQuery = "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

if ($statusInfo = $con->prepare($statusQuery)) {

    $statusInfo->bind_param("sss", $pk, $deleted, $notice);

   $statusInfo->execute();

   $statusInfo->close();
} else {

print_r($con->error);

}
}

echo "<form name=\"statusForm\" action=\"x.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">

<h1>Editing information for auction: ".$pk."</h1>
Löschung Ebay:
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"deleted\" value=\"checked\" ".$checkDeleted." align=\"right\"/>
<br />
Abmahnung:
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"notice\"  value=\"checked\" ".$checkNotice."  align=\"left\"/>
<br />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cmd\" value=\"submitinfo\" />
<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" />
</form>";
```

In the actual form/page, I have appropriate sanitization in place.

A big problem is that nothing is being inserted into the database and no errors are  being returned at all!

Comment: add input sanitization in the PHP too - client side sanitization can be turned off...

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. Use bind_param on $pk in the first select query. It's also vulnerable to xss-injections. Escape $pk with `htmlspecialchars()` when embedding it in html.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that unchecked checkbox does not contribute any values to a form when it is sent. When the deleted box is unchecked, there is no $_POST['deleted'] value set.

With that in mind, it looks like you don't actually set the value of $deleted if the checkbox is cleared. Use an idiom like this.

```
$deleted = isset($_POST["deleted"]) ? 1: 0;
```

Substitute the 1 and 0 with whatever values you want in your database table for the checked and unchecked states (in your case, "checked" and "")

Comment: If the checkbox is not checked, then the related value should surely remain as "", which would simply show it as not checked. I still don't understand why nothing is apparently being sent and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: You don't get any submitted values for unchecked checkboxes, I have modified my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...testing this now. Trying with $deleted = isset($_POST["deleted"]) ? "checked": ""; I sill think it is odd I don't get any errors

Comment: Hmm, nothing is going in the database still, and no errors..., I really don't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as Paul Dixon's answer, I've done this at times:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notice" value="not checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="notice" value="checked" checked="checked" />
```

If the user unchecks the checkbox, the hidden input's value gets sent instead. This way, `$_POST['notice']` is always sent to your script.

Answer (score -1):

I thought checkboxes should be done this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="notice1"  value="value1" checked="checked"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="notice2"  value="value2" checked="checked"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but then I can'T as easily do what I want to do. My appraoch works, as I stated, so it's fine.

Comment: You're thinking of radio buttons, I think. If the user checks both checkboxes, only the value2 is sent (unless you turn name="notice" into name="notice[]").

Comment: this was not an answer directly to the question, but more a tip on the html: the point a want to point at was, how to use the checked attribute on input fields.